# How to Dynamically load MockBeans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm developing some Integration Tests and to speed up the process I wanted to exploit the Template pattern for a quicker coverage.
This is my Template class

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class ControllerTestTemplate<D extends BaseDto, S extends ServiceTemplate>{
    protected D dto;
    @MockBean
    protected S service;
    protected String endpoint;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private static EasyRandom easyRandom;


public ControllerTestTemplate(D dto, String endpoint) {
    this.dto = dto;
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
}
@BeforeAll
public static void setUp(){
    EasyRandomParameters  easyRandom = new EasyRandom();
}

@Test
void saveWorks() throws Exception {
//given
    D d = (D) easyRandom.nextObject(dto.getClass());
    String json = new ObjectMapper()
            .writeValueAsString(d);

    when(service.save(eq(d))).thenReturn(d);
//when - then

    mockMvc.perform(post(endpoint)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(json))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
}
```

So that I cant just create a class that extends my Template for free coverage

```
public class ConcreteControllerTest extends ControllerTestTemplate<ConcreteDto,ConcreteService> {
        public ConcreteControllerTest() {
        super(new ConcreteDto(), "/concrete");
    }
}
```

Rightfully this is wrong, as Spring Boot cannot figure out exactly what Bean he should mock. I get this error when running the Test Suite above: `Unable to register mock bean ? expected a single matching bean to replace but found: [list of services]`

So my question is, can I define the exact Bean to Mock with @MockBean at runtime? Is there a way to make my idea work?

This is just a fake project, I don't think this will ever be applied in real scenarios, I was just curious if such implementation could work.

Comment: I think you are looking for how to dynamically register beans. Here is one post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75046275/460557 and found this one on google: https://medium.com/@venkivenki4b6/spring-dynamically-register-beans-in-4-ways-at-run-time-c1dc45dcbeb9 
See if it helps

Comment: The exception means that Spring found more bean candidates to match for ConcreteService than only one. Do you have couple of beans defined for that type? If so, you would need to specify @Qualifier in order to pick the one that you're interested in but your Template doesn't support it.