# In Spring Boot, how do I create a reusable configuration object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a number of different services that I want to configure and build in a similar way. For a simplified example, let's say that I have a `foo` client and a `bar` client and they each need to be configured with `host` and `port`. I would like to be able to write application configuration something like this:

```yaml
foo:
  host: foo.com
  port: 1234
bar:
  host: bar.com
  port: 1234
```

I would like to read the configuration for each into objects of the same class, preferably a record like:

```
record ClientConfiguration(String host, int port) {}
```

And in my configuration I would do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public Client fooClient(@Value("foo") ClientConfiguration configuration) {
      return Client.create(configuration)
   }

   // ... 
}
```

However, `@Value` could not be used like that and I can't find anything else that will work that way.

The only way I've found so far is to make my ClientConfiguration a classic bean with getters and setters, and then write this for every client:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
    public ClientConfiguration fooClientConfiguration() {
        return new ClientConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    public Client fooClient(ClientConfiguration fooClientConfiguration) {
        return Client.create(fooClientConfiguration);
    }
}
```

This feels clumsy and unfortunate to me. Is there a more direct way of achieving this?

Comment: Do you mean like what I write in the bottom of my question? I believe it has to be a bean with getters and setters, not a record, and I have to have this extra bean to carry the configuration rather than just injecting it as a value to my Client bean...

Comment: Have you read [Type-safe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi! Yes, I have. Are you referring to some specific variant of `@ConfigurationProperties` that I might have missed?

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought it covered this scenario as well, but looking at it again, it doesn't (it only covers fixed binding to a specific property prefix with `@ConstructorBinding`). IIRC there is a way to do this, but I don't have an example at hand, and my Google-fu seems to let me down here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to register all client beans dynamically without defining them in a configuration class.

Let's assume this is the content of `application.yaml`:

```
clients:
  - name: foo
    host: foo.com
    port: 1234
  - name: bar
    host: bar.com
    port: 1234
```

I made a slight modification to make it easier to handle.

Accordingly, the `ClientConfiguration` class should be defined as follows.

```java
public class ClientConfiguration {
  private String name;
  private String host;
  private Long port;
  
  // Getters and setters.
}
```

Next, the bean definitions should be registered to create beans dynamically. To do so, [the `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) needs to be implemented.

```java
public class ClientBeanDefinitionRegistrar implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
  public static final String PROPERTIES_PREFIX = "clients";
  private final List<ClientConfiguration> clients;

  public ClientBeanDefinitionRegistrar(Environment environment) {
    clients =
        Binder.get(environment)
            .bind(PROPERTIES_PREFIX, Bindable.listOf(ClientConfiguration.class))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    clients.forEach(client -> registerClientBeanDefinition(registry, client));
  }

  private void registerClientBeanDefinition(
      BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, ClientConfiguration client) {
    GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setBeanClass(Client.class);
    beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(() -> Client.create(client));
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(client.getName(), beanDefinition);
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
      throws BeansException {}
}
```

Additionally, define a configuration class for the `ClientBeanDefinitionRegistrar` bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class ClientBeanDefinitionRegistrarConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public static ClientBeanDefinitionRegistrar beanDefinitionRegistrar(Environment environment) {
    return new ClientBeanDefinitionRegistrar(environment);
  }
}
```

The bean method is static since such beans get initialized early in the container lifecycle.

As a result, all client beans, you define in `application.yaml`, are created dynamically and can be injected by name or as a collection. For example:

```java
@Autowired private List<Client> clients;
@Autowired private Client foo;
@Autowired private Client bar;
```

For reference: [Dynamically register Spring Beans based on properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046618/10231374)

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I recommend doing the following:

### Solution 1

Yaml properties:

```
clients:      
   foo:
      host: foo.com
      port: 1234
   bar:
      host: bar.com
      port: 5678
```

ClientConfigurationProperties:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ClientConfigurationProperties {

    private Map<String, ClientConfiguration> clients;
    
}
```

AppConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
class AppConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    Client foo(ClientConfigurationProperties clientConfigurationProperties) {
        return Client.create(clientConfigurationProperties.getClients().get("foo"));
    }
    
    @Bean
    Client bar(ClientConfigurationProperties clientConfigurationProperties) {
        return Client.create(clientConfigurationProperties.getClients().get("bar"));
    }
    
}
```

Alternative solutions:

### Solution 2

```
@Configuration
class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Client foo(
            @Value("${foo.host}") String host,
            @Value("${foo.port}") int port) {
        ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration(host, port);
        return Client.create(configuration);
    }
    
    @Bean
    Client bar(
            @Value("${bar.host}") String host,
            @Value("${bar.port}") int port) {
        ClientConfiguration configuration = new ClientConfiguration(host, port);
        return Client.create(configuration);
    }
    
}
```

### Solution 3

```
public interface PropertyExtractor<T> {

    T extract(String prefix);
        
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClientConfigurationPropertyExtractor implements PropertyExtractor<ClientConfiguration> {

    private final Environment environment;

    @Override
    public ClientConfiguration extract(String prefix) {
        String host = environment.getProperty(prefix + ".host");
        String port = environment.getProperty(prefix + ".port");
        return new ClientConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
    }
    
}

@Configuration
class AppConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    Client foo(PropertyExtractor<ClientConfiguration> clientConfigurationPropertyExtractor) {
        return Client.create(clientConfigurationPropertyExtractor.extract("foo"));
    }
    
    @Bean
    Client bar(PropertyExtractor<ClientConfiguration> clientConfigurationPropertyExtractor) {
        return Client.create(clientConfigurationPropertyExtractor.extract("bar"));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is what I do now, and while it works ok for a limited set of properties (like in this simplified example with `host` and `port`) it can get a bit unwieldy and error-prone to extend.